# Calculating Total Field Goals Using Poisson

Tags: probability, statistics

With the Super Bowl around the corner, I've been attempting to price various prop bets. My question is, can I use the Poisson distribution to calculate the odds of the total number of field goals being over/under a certain amount? So far, my approach has been to generate a table of the odds of each possible combination of field goals such as 3-0, and then sum up the probabilities of each of the events that would result in being over/under for the bet. Does this work? I feel like I might be overlooking some correlation between the number of field goals one team kicks and the number of field goals the other team kicks. I just used the average number of field goals kicked for the last 16 games or so to do all my calculations.

Comment: Interesting question! It would be nice to find out how good the Poisson model is, say for regular season games in the last decade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one article, [outline a solution](http://wizardofodds.com/ask-the-wizard/226/) to a simple betting situation using Poisson distribution

> Knowing that team A scores 1.5 goals per game on average, and team B
>   scores 1.2 goals per game on average, what are the chances that in a
>   game between A and B: 1) A will score more than B 2) B will score more
>   than A 3) Game finishes as a tie.

Using an Excel spreadsheet they show that

> - A wins = 44.14%
> - B wins = 30.37%
> - Tie = 25.48%

Modeling sports data is a hot topic now.  Read [Who's #1?: The Science of Rating and Ranking](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691154228).

---

The Poisson distribution has to do with the [law of rare events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_limit_theorem):

> If $n \to \infty,\; p \to 0 \text{ and }np \to \lambda$ then
>   $$\mathbb{P}[k\text{ successes}] = \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} \to e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$$
>   The Poisson distribution is a ``rare" limit of the Binomial distribution.

You should check that your favorite statistic, field goals, touchdowns, yards pass ... *actually* has a Poisson distribution.  It should be close and all you have to do is estimate the *rate*.  This rate should depend on all sorts of extraneous factors like weather, venue, turf, injuries, etc.